# CopyOnWriteArrayList - Iterator throw exceptions when removing element - for loop doesn't

Tags: java, loops, iterator

I am trying to understand CopyOnWriteArrayList. Normally as for my understanding we cannot remove elements in for loop while we can remove in iterator if it exists..

```
public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String arfs[]) {

    CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> copyOnWrite = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> ();

    copyOnWrite.add("One");
    copyOnWrite.add("Two");
    copyOnWrite.add("Three");
    copyOnWrite.add("Four");

    for(int i=0; i<copyOnWrite.size(); i++) {
        copyOnWrite.remove(i);
    }
 }

}
```

Why this is not throwing an exception, as i am trying to remove an element from CopyOnWriteArrayList...

```
Iterator<String> itr = copyOnWrite.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        itr.remove();
    }
```

But when using Iterator it is throwing an exception..normally this should be opposite right...

Comment: What exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docs regarding iterator of that collection

> The iterator does NOT support the remove method.

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html#iterator()

Normally your expectation is correct for eg `ArrayList` - where removing item in enchanced FOR loop will throw ConcurrentModificationException and using iterator will not, but this is different implementation - thus different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

No, the iterator is not supposed to make mutations, from the javadoc

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

"Element-changing operations on iterators themselves (remove, set, and add) are not supported. These methods throw UnsupportedOperationException."

In the first case it must be making a copy of the list upon mutation, which is the expected behavior for CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Comment: Thats why I asked what kind of exception he is getting.